# I Keep Getting "IndentationError: expected an indented block"

Tags: python, compiler-errors, python-turtle

My program is simple, i'm planing on making a console application where you can draw some art using turtle by some commands such as "left_star","left_circle" ext. When I tried to implement updates, it gives me the indentation error for some reason.Can you help me with this problem?

```
import turtle
import random
turtle.color('green', 'red')
turtle.begin_fill()
print(" ")
print("right_star: makes a right star.             ")
print(" ")
print("left_star: makes a star on the left.        ")
print(" ")
print("right_circle: makes a circle on the right.  ")
print(" ")
print("left_circle: makes a circle on the left side")
print(" ")
_input = input("What shape do you want to make? type 'help' if you want help: ")


turtle.Turtle()
print(turtle.pos())
if _input == "left_star":
    i = 0
    while  i != 10:
        turtle.forward(200)
        turtle.left(200)
        i += 1
        if  i > 9:
        #_input2 = input("What shape do you want to make? type 'help' if you want help: ")                      
    elif _input=="right_circle":
        while True:
            turtle.forward(70)   
            turtle.right(70)                                            
            _input2 = input("What shape do you want to make? type 'help' if you want help: ")               
    else _input == "right_star":
        while True:
            turtle.right(200)
            turtle.forward(200)
        while True:
            _input2 = input("What shape do you want to make? type 'help' if you want help: ") 
    elif _input == "left_circle":
        while True:
            turtle.left(70)    
            turtle.forward(70)
    elif _input == "help":
        print("right_star: makes a right star.             ")
        print("left_star: makes a star on the left.        ")
        print("right_circle: makes a circle on the right.  ")
        print("left_circle: makes a circle on the left side")
        print("PLEASE RESTART THE APPLICATION!'python opt.py'")
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [edit] your question to include the full error traceback, as that will show where the error is ocurring

Comment: `else _input == "right_star"` will cause an error. Do you mean `elif`? Also, the `if i > 9` above the comment requires some form of code below it. If you want to keep it without adding code, write `pass`. See also @DYZ 's answer.

Comment: ohh, thank you so much

Comment: it was meant to say elif, thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your `elif _input=="right_circle":` and all consecutive `elif`s are not aligned with `if _input == "left_star":`. Remove the unnecessary spaces in front of the `elif`s.

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate the help.